# black boxes instead of sprites on reload andengine

Tags: andengine, sprite, texture-atlas

My sprites (which are boxes themselves, but different colors) are all showing as black boxes the second time my andengine activity is loaded. It's odd because usually this problem is due to the texture atlas not being large enough, but I tried doubling the size of the atlas, and this didn't work. So here's the relevant code, any help would be much appreciated!

So to put it out there, the first time I load my game, everything is fine and perfect, but the second time, the sprites appear black.

I've seen other questions where the sprites appear as black boxes but for me they load fine the first time, which does not happen for other questions, and the answers which were given on the other questions did not work for me (they were, atlas needs to be power of two, and atlas is not big enough)

```
public void loadGameResources(){

    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    gameTextureAtlas = new BuildableBitmapTextureAtlas(activity.getTextureManager(), 512, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);

    blackTile = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(gameTextureAtlas, activity, "blacktile.png");
    greyTile = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(gameTextureAtlas, activity, "greytile.png");
    redTile = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(gameTextureAtlas, activity, "redtile.png");
    greenTile = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(gameTextureAtlas, activity, "greentile.png");
    Log.d(gameTextureAtlas+"","didn'tignore");
    loadFont();

    try{
        Log.d("LOPOLL","arrived");
        gameTextureAtlas.build(new BlackPawnTextureAtlasBuilder<IBitmapTextureAtlasSource, BitmapTextureAtlas>(0, 1, 0));

        Log.d("boom","arrived");

        gameTextureAtlas.load();
        Log.d("gotHere","arrived");
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("WrongPlace","arrived");
    }

}
```

(Resource unload method)

```
public void unloadGameResources(){
    if(gameTextureAtlas !=null){
    gameTextureAtlas.unload();
    }
    gameTextureAtlas = null;

//      blackTile = null;
//      greyTile = null;
//      redTile = null;
//      greenTile = null;

    }
```

The reason that I commented the section giving the tiletextures a null value is that doing this for some reason created a nullexception error even though I thought the textureregions would be reassigned textures upon reloading the activity as reloading the activity calls the loadgameresources() method

Comment: If, upon leaving the activity, I enter the 'settings activity' and leave it, the sprites are not boxes. Perhaps this information might be useful?

Comment: Guys so pretty much it's only pausing the activity not destroying it, how do I make it destroy the activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer guys.. System.exit(code) ensures the activity is exited properly. Dissapointed stack overflow was not able to answer this!